# Convert from struct (of char[]) to binary

Tags: c

I have to write an assembler program.
i get from input a string, and i do tests on the string, and export a word machine. [for imaginary processor in length 24 bits]

first, i build a struct to insert the part of "word machine", its looks like this:

```
typedef struct WORD_MACHINE{
    char opcode[6];
    char sourceAddressing[2];
    char sourceRegister[3];
    char destinationAddressing[2];
    char destinationRegister[3];
    char function[5];
    char are[3];
}wordMachine;
```

and for exampel after manipulation, the struct will look like this:

```
typedef struct WORD_MACHINE{
    char opcode[6]; -->"001000"
    char sourceAddressing[2]; -->"01"
    char sourceRegister[3]; -->"100"
    char destinationAddressing[2]; -->"01"
    char destinationRegister[3]; -->"010"
    char function[5]; -->"01010"
    char are[3]; -->"001"
}wordMachine;
```

i need to get the all parts and connect to one word machine:

```
in exampel: "001000011000101001010001"
```

i have a some questions:

1. how i can connect the all parts quickly?
2. Is the data structure in a sequence of memory so that I can address it directly, as if it were one long string?
3. i need to get this char[] "word machine", in the form of "binary number" (That is, the bits themselves will express a sequence of binary code in memorey).  how to do that?
4. And finally I need to convert the sequence which is a binary number, to the hexadecimal number.

i'm need you help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try and focus on one question at a time. Show us *some* code for context, even if it's broken, misguided, or completely confused. We can hammer something into shape. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Why not test this C code and look at how the compiler lays that memory structure out in memory. Hint: `&wm.opcode[0]` and so on or just look in a debugger that displays things in memory. Use a pattern like `ABCDEF`, `GH`, and so on.

Comment: thanks.
its my first time here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the answer to 2 - C structs are in fact contiguous chunks of memory of fixed length. With this in mind, you can "walk" through each char of your struct in order, and 'converting' each char to a bit you will store in one unsigned variable.

So, you can do something like this

```
unsigned createBinaryFromWordStruct(wordMachine* w){
    char* t = (char*) w;
    unsigned instruction = 0;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i<24; i++){
        instruction<<=1;
        if(*t == '1') 
            instruction|=1;
        t++;
    return instruction;
```

This will give you an unsigned int holding the value of your instruction.
You can then proceed to print it in hex or binary (you can print to hex using "%x", but be warned that there is no built-in shortcut to print it as binary).